# XCode 13 failed to generate profdata file

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, llvm, code-coverage

We have always been using the following code in our PR pipeline for years and it worked.

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration dev -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject_Mu -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8' test -derivedDataPath DerivedData CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

Normally, the above code generated `.profraw` and `.profdata` at folder: `DerivedData/Build/ProfileData/41E444A5-D124-4222-82C2-EB33DCDBF2FC/`

Until recently, our hosted agent upgraded from `XCode 12` to `XCode 13`, the above code generates only the `.profraw` and ends with the error below

```
warning: DerivedData/Build/ProfileData/41E444A5-D124-4222-82C2-EB33DCDBF2FC/B8590BD3-CF44-4308-95CF-20FBFFEF3568-24496.profraw: Failed to uncompress data (zlib)
error: No profiles could be merged.
```

We even tried to run this code hoping this would fix the issue:

```
xcrun llvm-profdata merge DerivedData/Build/ProfileData/*/*.profraw -output generated.profdata
```

But it does not work. We get the same error

```
warning: DerivedData/Build/ProfileData/41E444A5-D124-4222-82C2-EB33DCDBF2FC/B8590BD3-CF44-4308-95CF-20FBFFEF3568-24496.profraw: Failed to uncompress data (zlib)
error: No profiles could be merged.
```

Now our PR pipeline is stuck and we can't work because this script is needed to generate unit test coverage data. And the pipeline is always failing.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, others have reported the same problem https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696934, I have been searching for a solution for the last days.

Comment: @ChristosKoninis have you tried on a different version of XCode 13 ? I tried on XCode 13.2.1 , also have you tried on a different iOS version?  I tried on 14.5 
Also are you using Mac M1 chip ? For I use M1 and I get several but non-related issue due to this chip

Comment: I only have tried XCode 13.2.1, with iOS 15.2, 14.5 and 13.x. I have Intel CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by setting `GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS` to **NO**. For some reason the extra code added by LLVM profiling instrumentation is interfering with the code coverage. I am not sure if this is the expected behavior; I will file a bug and follow up if I have any further information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am glad this workaround worked for you. However, mine already has `GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS` to `NO` by default before the problem occured

Comment: We start to have the same issue on Xcode 14, did anyone found a work around for it?